# Ubuntu 16.04 internet connection issue

Tags: 16.04, internet

Just like title says, I have issue with the internet connection and I already know many people have ask this question but every answer in the internet doesn't solve my problem.

So the detail is this. My internet connection error and I've search any possible answer on internet and found problem if bluetooth and wifi chipset are same. The suggestion is to turn off the bluetooth and reboot. Surprisingly it is work ... But not really work. I can go into google but not any website, just google.com. I try ping www.google.com and the result is host unknown (sort of it) and this is what confuse me, I can go only to google.com and not anywhere else.

So if anyone knows what my problem is, it would be great!!!!

Comment: You have two distinct problems and that is probably the reason why you can't find suitable answers. One is a DNS problem and may need to use different DNS, the other is - supposedly - a BT-WiFi coexistence issue that affects a really small number of cards. The solution for the DNS problems is hardware independent, the other is totally hardware dependent: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: already enter the command and the output is like this:

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2c97]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)